# Dynamically assign values in C#

Tags: c#

I am looking for an easiest way to assign values to the properties of a class dynamically.
In my WPF App, I have a list header values as shown below :

```
    Name   Mark  Class --> header values (Name, Mark, Class these are the 3 headers)
    ----   ---  -----
    Nick    10   5
    Tom     12   7
   John     09   4
```

Sometimes, the header values changes:

```
   Name  Mark   Percent  Phone  --> 4 header values 
   ----  -----  -------  -----
```

So we cannot predict the number of headers. Sometimes it will be 5, sometimes it will be 2,
sometimes the number of headers will be 6, etc

So I created a class Named StudentMark with following properties.

```
  public class StudentMark
  {
    [Order]
    public double? Col1 {get;set;}
    [Order]
    public double? Col2 {get;set;}
    [Order]
    public double? Col3 {get;set;}
    - - - - -
    [Order]
    public double? Col10 {get;set;}
  }
```

When I get the list from server, I assign the values to the properties of the student mark class are shown as below code. This is doing for plotting a graph. We don't know the column header values in advance, we do like these.

```
       StudentMark sm = new StudentMark();

  var properties = from property in typeof(StudentMark).GetProperties()
                                         where Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(OrderAttribute))
                                         orderby ((OrderAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OrderAttribute), false).Single()).Order
                                         select property;

                        //PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(StudentMark).GetProperties();

                        foreach (string str in HeaderColumns)
                        {
                            var d1 = csv.GetField<string>(str); // taking cell value

                            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                            {
                                if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Double?))
                                {
                                    if (property.GetValue(sm) == null)
                                    {
                                        property.SetValue(sm, d1);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                         }
```

this is working but very very very slow. Is there anyway to do it without using reflection ??

Comment: This doesn't make sens ... if you wana dynamic than use `DataTable` or collection of dictionaries (like `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>`

Comment: If you can't predict the headers, how could you predefine the properties?

Comment: @Selvin could you please show some sample code or anything

Comment: Well the problem is that we don't know how you wana use it ... but useage can be `var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection); var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());` ... and you have dynamic table ... then you can use `dt.Rows[x]["ColumnName"]` to get value ... you can also bind `DataTable` to `DataGrid` in WPF, but again we don't know how you wana use it

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep typed data separate from arbitrary untyped data. So if you want to represent a table of arbitrary user defined data you would do it something like:

```
public class MyTable{
    public List<string> Headers {get;}
    public List<List<string>> Rows {get;}
}
```

If the only thing you will be doing is presenting it to the user, and reading writing csv-files, such an representation is perfectly appropriate.

It is only when you need to *use* the data for something you need to use actual types to represent the data. But this can be quite complicated and would involve a lot of data validation to ensure the data is on the correct format.

You could for example have logic to check if each header has some specific value, and then parse the values for each row to a set of predefined types. If either the headers have incorrect values, or the parsing of some value fails, you would give an error and let the user deal with the problem.

If you want minimize the risk of mistakes, you should make them impossible in the first place, or detect them as early as possible, i.e. enforce the correct header names, parse values as soon as they are entered etc.

If you need to combine typed data with untyped data you could for example use a dictionary:

```
public class MyDataRow{
    public string name {get;}
    public int Mark {get;}
    public Dictionary<string, string> UserDefinedData {get;}
```

The user defined data would just be treated as an opaque data blob, tracked thru the system, but not used for any computation, or if it is, with a great deal of error checking.